# Laravel: How can I use Group By in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am trying to get all slots, then group them by room. Within my view, I want to have a row of the room:

```
<tr>
    <td>Room ID 1</td>
    <td>Slot ID 1</td>
    <td>Slot ID 2</td>
    <td>Slot ID 3</td>
    .................
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Room ID 2</td>
    <td>Slot ID 1</td>
    <td>Slot ID 2</td>
    <td>Slot ID 3</td>
    .................
</tr>
```

I believe I am close, but not sure of the "Laravel way". The data looks good - as in, the query is getting/grouping correctly, I think my struggle is understanding how to loop through the collection.

**MyController.php**

```
public function routineViewDayWise()
{
    $sunday_routines = Routine::where('day_id', 1)->orderBy('room_id')->get()->groupBy('room_id');
    return view('day_wise_routine', compact('sunday_routines'));
}
```

In my view I can see I am getting this:

**MyView.blade.php**

```
#items: array:4 [▼
2 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1323 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Routine {#1339 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Routine {#1340 ▶}
  ]
}
4 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1322 ▶}
6 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1336 ▶}
8 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1335 ▶}]
```

**SOLUTION**

Here is what my view looks like to get the output I wanted.

**MyView.blade.php**

```
@foreach($sunday_routines as $room_id => $routines)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $room_id }}</td>
    @foreach($routines as $routine)
        <td>{{ $routine->slot_id }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi friend please update the following as put **groupBy()** before **get()**

```
public function routineViewDayWise()
{
   $sunday_routines = Routine::where('day_id', 1)->orderBy('room_id')->groupBy('room_id')->get();
   return view('day_wise_routine', compact('sunday_routines'));
}
```